# Reload fragments data wrt language on switch change in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created a quiz with the help of View pager and fragments.
Now i want to reload the fragments on language switch but no luck.
and alose how can i track the state of a fragment as view pager loads 2 fragments by default

On language change i called notifyDataSetChanged() and also override getItemPosition and return POSITION_NONE from adapter.

Set adapter

```
questionAdapter = new QuestionAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), questionList, is_hindi);
        viewPager.setAdapter(questionAdapter);
```

This is question adapter:

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Question> questionList;
    private Boolean is_hindi;
    public QuestionAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Question> QuestionList, Boolean is_hindi) {
        super(fm);
        this.questionList = QuestionList;
        this.is_hindi = is_hindi;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        return QuestionFragment.setInstance(questionList, i, is_hindi);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
//        return super.getItemPosition(object);
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return questionList.size();
    }
```

and this is question fragment function:

```
public static QuestionFragment setInstance(List<Question> questionList, int i, Boolean is_hin)
    {

        is_hindi = is_hin;
        Question question = questionList.get(i);

         QuestionFragment fragment=new QuestionFragment();
         Bundle b=new Bundle();

         b.putString("q_no", Integer.toString(question.getQ_no()));
         b.putInt("selected_opt", question.getSelected_option());
//        Log.d("qno", Integer.toString(questionModel.getQ_no()));
        Log.d("qno", Integer.toString(question.getId()));
         Log.d("selected opt", Integer.toString(question.getSelected_option()));


         b.putString("qid", Integer.toString(question.getId()));
         b.putString("question_H", question.getQuestion_H());
         b.putString("question_E", question.getQuestion_E());
         b.putStringArrayList("option_hindi", question.getH_optionList());
         b.putStringArrayList("option_english", question.getE_optionList());

         fragment.setArguments(b);
         return fragment;
    }
```

and on create view i have set question

Comment: You have to reload the activity itself.

Comment: ok, but in case where i want to start the fragment from the paused position than how can i load fragments from there because it loads only 2 start question fragments no other to compare for that position